# Выбор полностью заполненной строки

Tags: sql, база-данных, plsql

Добрый день.
Имеется таблица, содержащая 50 и более столбцов.
Каким образом из нее выбрать только полностью заполненные строки, не имеющие значение столбца null? Для каждого столбца дописывать is not null? БД Oracle 9i.

Comment: Да, для каждого столбца `is not null`. Как альтернативный вариант, добавить еще 1 колонку с бинарным признаком и заполнять ее вручную или тригером при апдейтах и инсертах

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так или иначе, но придется перечислить в запросе все столбцы. Но при этом есть пара способов схитрить.

1. Например, у вас все столбцы числовые или даты. Тогда можно воспользоваться тем свойством, что `NULL` в арифметическом выражении дает `NULL` в результате. Например:

   ```
   select *
     from table
    where (col1 + col2 + col3 + ... + col50) is not null
   ```

   С датами сложнее немного, их нельзя просто складывать, но зато их можно попарно вычесть (получив интервалы) и полученные интервалы сложить между собой. Писанины лишь немного меньше, логика запроса становится менее очевидная, в общем, овчинка не стоит выделки.
2. <s>Можно сделать `UNPIVOT` и потом `count(*) = 50`</s> Не, нельзя, у вас 9-я версия...
3. Если вам повезло и работодатель раскошелился на PL/SQL Developer, то там можно, кликнув правой кнопкой на названии таблицы, скопировать в буфер обмена список названий всех столбцов (но я с ним давно не работал, не помню, где конкретно эта опция вызывается). Дальше <kbd>ctrl+V</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl+H</kbd> и автозамена запятых на `is not null and`.

Comment: спасибо за совет, plsql developer в наличии.